# Normal force on bar after letting go of it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I want to understand the following question, both from a theoretical and practical standpoint. Given the following image:

[image]

Originally, the system is in equilibrium thanks to the force A. I am asked what the normal force the table exerts on the bar would be right after the force A stopped being applied. I thought it was a relatively simple question, as using newtons second law:
$$N+A-mg=0$$
$$NL/2-AL/2=0$$
Which gives that both A and L should have a magnitude of mg/2. Thus I thought that right after A stopped being applied N wouldn't change, and remain $mg/2$
But the correct answer is $N=mg/4$, which is obtained through a complex process involving polar coordinates. Can this answer be obtained in an intuitive way? Why is my initial approach wrong?

Comment: If you take strictly the "instant" that A is removed, the change in load needs time to propagate along the length of the rod (at the speed of sound in the rod) and nothing about the normal force would change. Seems like an underspecified question

Answer (score 0):

When A becomes zero the system is no longer in equilibrium, it has acceleration.

Vertical force.  N-mg=ma_c
Clockwise Moment about C.   NL/2 =I alpha

where I is moment of inertia about C.

The third equation is circular motion of C about A

-(L/2)alpha = a_c.

Answer (score 0):

Your equations are correct until rod is in equilibrium. But, after force A is no longer applied, the rod will rotate in a circular path about B for a very short period. 
$mg - N' = ma$ (a is the acceleration the center of gravity of rod)
$mgL/2 = mL²/3*α$ (Torque equation about B)
$α = 3g/2L$
$a = α*L/2$ (the acceleration of the center of gravity of rod is due to rotation of rod about B)
On solving, we get $N' = mg/4$